# How can I find Midsummer (Juhannus) celebration spots nearby Helsinki?

Tags: finland, festivals, helsinki

The title says it all, really.

I plan to be in Helsinki for mid-summer, and I know it is quite a big event in Finland. If possible I would like to participate in some local celebrations. How can I locate spots where there will be public/open celebrations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very few people are in Helsinki for the midsummer. Traditionally for midsummer people leave for their cottages and the Finnish cities are deserted. During midsummer you should be prepared for shorter opening hours or stores being closed.

Perhaps the most traditional midsummer celebration in Helsinki is in Seurasaari, which is an island close to the city. The website for the Midsummer celebrations is [here](https://www.seurasaarisaatio.fi/juhannusvalkeat/juhannusaatto/) and according to it they have a bonfire, dances and traditional performances. If you want to find a stereotypically Finnish midsummer this is probably the way to go.

Some more modern events might include music festivals such as the one in [Hernesaari](http://www.hernesaarenranta.fi/tapahtumat/) or [Stadin Juhannus](https://www.stadinjuhannus.com/), which is also on an island near Helsinki.

Besides these, there is also a large number of smaller celebrations. Kaivopuisto and Hietaniemi are at least common places for gatherings. Unlike the others these two should be free as they are public parks, but you are not likely to find as much organized celebrations here. They should probably still have at least a bonfire and people enjoying summer at the very least.

Comment: +1, Seurasaari is the place to go.  Expect more kids & oldies than a bacchanal on the streets (that's Vappu on May 1st).

Comment: Luckily I was already planning to visit Seurasaari :D Thanks for the warning about midsummer and opening hours. :)